# Cognos 11 SSO in .NET

Tags: cognos

I have a .NET web application that someone implemented Cognos SSO for it (it is using cookies to store the credential information for Cognos!), at the moment when I go to the **Cognos** through this application I just can see the report in HTML format and when I want to see the reports in the other format PDF, Excel and etc I get this error "CV-0015 The user does not have the assigned capability to generate 'spreadsheetML' output." The IBM solution is: **http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21976205**

But the other issue is when I go directly to the Cognos everything is fine.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on the item that wrote it up.
and I find that the issue was about the Cognos SDK,
in the application that I developed I used **Cognos 11 SDK** , but in the server the other team deployed with **Cognos 10 SDK**.